# using while loop to compare loan payment with monthly interest - logic error

Tags: string, if-statement, while-loop, logic

I am currently working on a while loop that should get the following information from the user- loan amount, annual interest, and monthly payment. It should compare monthly interest to the monthly payment and if the interest for the first month exceeds or is equal to the designated payment, a dialog opens up asking for a larger amount until the monthly payment is higher than the interest.

It seems to work fine in certain cases (if i type 1000 for the loan, 12% interest, and any payment below 121, the program asks for a larger payment). But if I enter a loan amount and a monthly payment that are close to eachother (500 loan amount 400 monthly payment) i receive the error dialog stating that I did not enter a large enough amount. *Huh!?*

Here's my code if you can take a look. Thanks!

```
package program6;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LoanAmount2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String loanAmountString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the amount for your loan.");
        double loanAmount = Double.parseDouble(loanAmountString);
        String annualInterestString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your annual interest rate.");
        double annualInterestRate = Double.parseDouble(annualInterestString);
        annualInterestRate = 1 + (annualInterestRate / 100);
        String monthlyPaymentString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the amount for your monthly payment.");
        double monthlyPayment = Double.parseDouble(monthlyPaymentString);
        double monthlyInterestRate = 1 + (annualInterestRate / 12);
        double monthlyInterest = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate;
        while (monthlyInterest >= monthlyPayment) {
            monthlyPaymentString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Your payment only covers the interest on your loan. Please enter a larger amount for your monthly payment.");
            monthlyPayment = Double.parseDouble(monthlyPaymentString);
            break;
        }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran this script and noticed your problem. The line:

```
double monthlyInterestRate = 1 + (annualInterestRate / 12);
```

Should read:

```
double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12;
```

If you add one to this your while loop will always evaluate to true, because you are multiplying the full loan amount by 1.xx

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying to break this problem into smaller pieces. You repeat this pattern several times in the program:

```
    String annualInterestString =
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter your annual interest rate.");
    double annualInterestRate =
        Double.parseDouble(annualInterestString);
```

I think it would be easier to read your code if you provided a method like the following:

```
double prompt_for_number(String prompt) {
    /* show dialog box */
    /* parse string into a Double */
    /* return number */
}
```

This would let you re-write your code more like this:

```
loanAmount = prompt_for_number("Enter the amount for your loan.");
annualInterestRate = prompt_for_number("Enter your annual interest rate.");
```

This would make it far easier to see the flow of calculations involved. (And would have made the actual error you came here to find that much easier to spot.)

Comment: great advice. i don't think i'm really at that level in my programming yet (haven't reached methods) but i am gonna keep that in mind, thank you